# Wordpress add media HTTP error

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a very funny problem.

I installed wordpress 3.9.1 on my server, I didn't change any wordpress file. I just unzip files and add to ftp.

when i tried to add some media file wordpress media uploader show to me this error line :

Here is Jpg from error message
http://funnyfennel.net/error.jpg

ERROR : HTTP error.

Comment: Okay - thanks for the information. What is your question? What does your error log say?

Comment: Make sure to change the permissions of the folder `wp-content` and its descendants to 777 (read-write).

Comment: Check you dir wp-content permissions, http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

Answer (score 0):

I think problem may be when you upload an image, there is a chance that your comments will show in the response coming from ajax which causes error to show. I have been through the same problem and find that my comments are showing in the response.when i removed it images are uploading nicely.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still getting the HTTP Error, ask your hosting provider to disable the PHP module imagick- it fixed it for me.